# anchor arrow start position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, arrows, tikz-styles

Attached below is the minimum working example. I would like the arrow to end at the 
west anchor of the node "operation".  I tried anchor and few other possibilities but they don't seem to affect the edge position.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}  
\begin{document}    
\tikzstyle{data}=[circle,shade,fill=blue!60, draw]
\tikzstyle{operator}=[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, fill=cyan, draw=cyan]   

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[data] (uncurated) {content};  
\path node[operator] (schematize) [below = of uncurated.south]{operation}
edge[<-,thick]  node[auto]{\tiny flow} (uncurated.south);  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please ensure that the posted code can be cut and pasted to into a document. The version you had posted had all the square brackets escaped fro some reason.

Comment: `\path node[operator, below=of uncurated] (schematize) {operation} (schematize.west) edge[<-,thick]  node[auto]{\tiny flow} (uncurated.south);` works for me.

Comment: Actually, this solution works better. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be easier to just use a separate draw command and specify the `in=` and `out=` angles:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}  
\begin{document}    
\tikzstyle{data}=[circle,shade,fill=blue!60, draw]
\tikzstyle{operator}=[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, fill=cyan, draw=cyan]   

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[data] (uncurated) {content};  
\path node[operator] (schematize) [below = of uncurated.south]{operation}
edge[<-,thick]  node[auto]{\tiny flow} (uncurated.south);  
\path [->, thick, red] (uncurated.south) edge (schematize.west);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[data] (uncurated) {content};  
\path node[operator] (schematize) [below = of uncurated.south]{operation}
edge[<-,thick]  node[auto]{\tiny flow} (uncurated.south);  
\path [->, thick, blue] (uncurated.south) edge[out=-145, in=180] (schematize.west);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works. Thanks so much. For some reason reading the manual didn't give me a hint that I could mix the draw and edge primitives.

Comment: @Sandeep You shouldn't. Use `\path` if you use `edge` and not `\draw`. Do you see the lonely blue up-arrow at the content node?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel by lonely you mean the arrow head is dislodged from trunk of the arrow? If so, yes. Will you path and edge.

Comment: @Sandeep Yes, that's caused by using `\draw` and `edge` together. The reason is a zero-length line from and to `(uncurated.south)`. The calculated direction for such a zero-length line is 90° (`atan(∞)`). The `edge` operator creates sub-paths.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks, I did not know that one should use `\path` instead of `\draw` with an `edge`. I normally don't use `edge` and am used to using `to` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the easiest way to achieve the good results in TikZ is to place nodes first and then draw the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{data}=[circle,shade,fill=blue!60, draw]
\tikzstyle{operator}=[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, fill=cyan, draw=cyan]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [data] (uncurated) {content};
\node [operator] (schematize) [below=of uncurated] {operation};
\draw [-stealth] (uncurated) -- node [auto, swap] {\tiny flow} (schematize);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [data] (uncurated) {content};
\node [operator] (schematize) [below=of uncurated] {operation};
\draw [-stealth] (uncurated) -- node [auto, swap] {\tiny flow} (schematize.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]

Note that you do not have to use anchors always (e.g., `below=of uncurated` is the same as `below=of uncurated.south` and placing only node names in `\draw` allow TikZ to calculate the anchors automagically.